# Proper way to call a suspended function in ktor

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

i would like to start a process is active while my ktor server is up.

```
suspend fun doWork(){
    while(true){
        delay(2000L)
        printit("I did work")
    }
}
```

I have read that best practice is to avoid runBlocking and GlobalScope.

so i think i should create a custom scope for the coroutine to run in.

(the job is using some db calls so i did this)

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)
```

i then call it from my main function

```
fun main() {
   val runningJob =  scope.launch{
      doWork()
    }
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "127.0.0.1") {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK, HTML::index)

            }
            static("/static") {
                resources()
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Is this the proper way to do this?  Most of the coroutine examples kind of leave out calling from non suspend functions.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I believe the code you provided is good enough but this question might be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `(the job is using some db calls so i did this)` and describe why do you need an instance of `Job` in the coroutine context?

Comment: Aleksi, The service is doing both reads and writes to a postgres database via jetbrains expose.  

Also i dont think i need the job, i was just experimenting with stopping the process for learning purposes but i dont think i will be doing that real world.